# What is the maximum length of a textbox in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to know the maximum length of a textbox in ssrs. How much data can it accomodate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max length is 32k.

Answer (score 0):

The Maximum Length of the textbox in SSRS 2012 is 4680 Characters.